# h:outputStylesheet not inserted when using FullAjaxExceptionHandler

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I'm using the OmniFaces [FullAjaxExceptionHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) to display error pages. The error pages are shown correctly, but I'm having issues with the styling of those pages.

My application is using a template which has CSS classes loaded in the `<h:body>` section like the following. `<h:outputStylesheet name="css/theme.css" library="theme"  />`

I found the BalusC answer at [h:body not rerendered when using FullAjaxExceptionHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224613/hbody-not-rerendered-when-using-fullajaxexceptionhandler) to be helpful for changing the body tag. But I'm stumped on why the [FullAjaxExceptionHandler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) isn't  replacing the children of individual `<head>` element. It appears like all `<h:outputStylesheet>` elements are ignored no matter where they are located.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Which JSF impl/version?

Comment: JSF 2.3, Omnifaces 3.2, Payara 5 183 Full. I believe Payara uses Mojarra 2.4.0-m01.payara-p5 a fork of Mojarra 2.4.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with Omnifaces 3.2 and Myfaces 2.3

Comment: I should also mention I am using JoinFaces 3.3.0 in Spring Boot for my container.

Answer (score 1):

I know this quite an old question but I have only recently encountered it and it has only just been solved as of 15/May/2021.

The headline is that this issue is solved in the versions of OmniFaces >= 3.11.1. At the time of writing this, OmniFaces 3.11.1 is a Maven Snapshot build.

The problem was caused by the Mojarra implementation of JSF 2.3 attempting to avoid outputting HTML links to CSS resources twice. It does this by recording a list of all of the resources that it thinks have been output. Then if a further attempt is made to output the same resource then the second and further attempts are ignored. The list is stored in a JSF attribute called "/javax.faces.resource", which is the value of ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER.

In the case of Primefaces/JSF rendering the response to an Ajax request generated by an Primefaces component, the rendering replaces the entire page including the resources that had already been rendered. In this case the "/javax.faces.resource" attribute should be cleared by OmniFaces' FullAjaxExceptionHandler to allow the re-rendering of the resources.

The problem was tracked and solved in OmniFaces cases [627](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/627) & [630](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/630)