# Error-page in WEB-INF not found when using PrimeExceptionHandler

Tags: jsf, primefaces, exceptionhandler

In my `web.xml`, I have

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/expired.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

But if a `ViewExpiredException` is thrown (Non - AJAX), it ends up in a `404 - Not Found` basic page with an url `/WEB-INF/errorpages/expired.xhtml`. If I change the location to `/expired.xhtml` (and copy the file `expired.xhtml` under `webapp` directory) it works fine and the url is `/expired.xhtml` after the `ViewExpiredException` is thrown.

Well, the file `expired.xhtml` should be in WEB-INF directory. Why is it not working with the WEB-INF path ?

Comment: You can reproduce the problem with primefaces-showcase : move viewExpired.xhtml to WEB-INF and modify web.xml. Test with the "ExceptionHandler" show case.

Comment: What exception handler do you use? Does it redirect to the error location?

Comment: You are right. I was using `org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandler` which does a redirect to the exception page. Hence the 404 error if it is in WEB-INF.

Comment: it SHOULD not be in WEB-INF, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out you are using the PrimeFaces `PrimeExceptionHandler`. This handler will redirect you to the error location, which will fail if the location is within the `WEB-INF` folder. To fix this you can use no specific handler or use one that does not redirect.

I personally use a customized version of the OmniFaces [`FullAjaxExceptionHandler`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) (which does support locations within the `WEB-INF` folder).

Comment: The OmniFaces FullAjaxExceptionHandler does the job. I got then a css problem. This post can fix it : https://stackoverflow.com/q/43224613/14946729

Comment: It might be possible to overcome this limitation via another ExceptionHandler but its not a good pattern to put views inside WEB-INF, see my answer

Comment: The error pages in omnifaces are in WEB-INF. You don't want those pages bookmarkable.

Answer (score 0):

Files inside WEB-INF are not serveable via browser without forward/rewrite

So just dont put views in WEB-INF, thats not a good pattern

Comment: error pages should not be bookmarkable.